# simplest inheritance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use OOPs in javascript. What i am trying is,

I have 2 classes say `classA` and `classB`. I am inheriting classA in classB. Like :

```
 function classA(){
    this.propA = "somevalue of A";
 }

 function classB(){
    classB.prototype = new classA();              //inheriting
    classB.prototype.constructor = classB;        //updating constructor defination
    this.propB = "somevalue of B";
 }
```

Now i created the object of classB :

```
var classBObject = new classB();
```

and than trying to access base class property value with :

```
alert(classBObject.propA);      //here i am expecting "somevalue of A"
```

but the alert shows me empty. Can anybody please tell me what i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Javascript is a [prototype-based language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), not a [class-based language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming).  So, technically there are no classes.  
In Javascript, objects inherit directly from other objects, unlike in other class-based languages, where objects inherit from classes.  There are 5 types in Javascript: *String*, *Number*, *Boolean*, *Undefined*, and *Null*.  Everything else is an *object*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the prototype assignment of classB outside the constructor:

```
function classA(){
    this.propA = "somevalue of A";
 }

 function classB(){
    // classB.prototype.constructor = classB;
    // ^ no need for this, constructor will be overwritten
    //   by classB.prototype = new classA
    this.propB = "somevalue of B";
 }

 classB.prototype = new classA; // assing prototype for classB here
```